# Extend parent div height after jQuery accordion expand

Tags: jquery, height, accordion, expand

I have a jQuery accordion placed in a sidebar, with the sidebar div set to height 100% so the sidebar extends down the entire browser window. The problem is, when I expand the jQuery accordion, the sidebar height is not updated so the accordion extends out beyond the bounds of the sidebar which is visible when the user scrolls down.

How can I update the sidebar to 100% height after the accordion is finished animating outwards, then again update it after it is contracted to prevent an extra long sidebar that scrolls?